# Automatically display fix-it errors

Tags: xcode

Xcode 4 detects errors as you type the code. Unfortunately all it does is display a tiny red circle on the side. To actually see the message you have to aim into this circle and click every freaking time (this is very annoying on a laptop.) I'm new to Cocoa and Objective-C and this is really slowing me down.

Is there a way to display the error *message* automatically as an error is detected?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to automatically expand the in-line live issues that XCode 4 generates, short of compiling. However, you can have the Navigator pane on the left side display your list of issues, which is almost as good. The keyboard shortcut is `cmd + 4`, and `cmd + 1` returns the navigator to the file tree. Those shortcuts just become my new best friends!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Editor > Show Issues` or `Editor > Issues > Show All Issues`. The keyboard shortcut for the latter is `ctrl-commmand-M` (or `⌃⌘ M`).